# HTML5 based game doesn't show up on browser?

Tags: javascript, css, html, flappy-bird-clone

Recently, i made a game on codepen.io called flappy bird an it was working fine there but when i tried to show it on my website it doesn't show up anything.

Can someone tell what's missing or what is the problem in my code.
here is the code ( sorry it's too long , i know but i need help ):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#stage {
    display:block;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    margin:auto;
}
body{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

  background:#333;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||                            
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
    function(cb){
      return setTimeout(cb, 1000/60);
    };
})()

var can = document.getElementById("stage"),
    ctx = can.getContext('2d'),
    wid = can.width,
    hei = can.height,
    player, floor, pillars, gravity, thrust, running, 
    rainbows, colider, score, gPat, pPat, trans, termVel, pillGap, 
    pillWid, pillSpace, speed, stars, high,
    sprite = document.createElement("img");
sprite.src = "http://www.cutmypic.com/uploads/title85083782.png";
//sprite.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy3qB.gif";
sprite.onload = function(){
    sprite.style.height = 0;
    loop();
};
sprite.width = 34;
sprite.height = 21;


document.body.appendChild(sprite);

function init() {
    high = localStorage.getItem("high") || 0;

    player = {
        x: 1 / 3 * wid,
        y: 2 / 5 * hei,
        r: 13,
        v: 0
    };
    speed = 2.5;
    floor = 4 / 5 * hei;
    pillars = [];
    rainbows = [];
    stars = [];
    gravity = .30;
    thrust = gravity * -21;
    termVel = -thrust + 2;
    running = false;
    colider = false;
    score = 0;
    trans = 0;
    pillGap = 135;
    pillWid = 55;
    pillSpace = pillWid*3;
    pPat = ctx.createPattern((function(){
      var can = document.createElement("canvas"),
          ctx = can.getContext("2d");

        can.width = 60;
        can.height = 60;

        ["green", "green", "green", 
         "#3b5998", "green", "#3b5998"].forEach(function(color, i){
           ctx.fillStyle = color;

           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.moveTo(i*10, 0);
           ctx.lineTo(i*10+10, 0);
           ctx.lineTo(0, i*10+10);
           ctx.lineTo(0, i*10);
           ctx.closePath();
           ctx.fill();

           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.moveTo(i*10, 60);
           ctx.lineTo(i*10+10, 60);
           ctx.lineTo(60, i*10+10);
           ctx.lineTo(60, i*10);
           ctx.closePath();
           ctx.fill();
         });

      return can;
    })(), "repeat");
    gPat = ctx.createPattern((function(){
        var can = document.createElement("canvas"),
            ctx = can.getContext("2d");

        can.width = 32;
        can.height = 32;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(16,16);
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI/4);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#79CDCD";
        ctx.fillRect(-64,-64,128,128);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#528B8B";
        ctx.fillRect(-8,-64,8,128);
        ctx.fillRect(14.5,-64,8,128);
        ctx.restore();

        return can;
    })(), "repeat");
}


function render() {
    trans -= speed;
    rainbows = rainbows.filter(function(r){
        r.x -= speed;
        return r.x > -speed;
    });
    if (trans % speed === 0){
        rainbows.push({x:player.x-10, y:player.y - (trans%50/25|0)*2 - 1});
    }

    stars = stars.filter(function(s){
        trans % 10 || (s.r += 1);
        s.x -= speed;
        return s.x > -speed && s.r < 10;
    });
    if(trans % 20 === 0){
      stars.push({
        x: Math.round(Math.random()*(wid-50)+100), 
        y:Math.round(Math.random()*floor), 
        r:0
      });
    }


    // backdrop
    ctx.fillStyle = "#418bbc";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, wid, hei);

    //stars
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    stars.forEach(function (s){
        ctx.fillRect(s.x, s.y - s.r-2, 2, s.r/2);
        ctx.fillRect(s.x - s.r-2, s.y, s.r/2, 2);
        ctx.fillRect(s.x, s.y+s.r + 2, 2, s.r/2);
        ctx.fillRect(s.x+s.r + 2, s.y, s.r/2, 2);

        ctx. fillRect(s.x + s.r, s.y + s.r, 2, 2);
        ctx. fillRect(s.x - s.r, s.y - s.r, 2, 2);
        ctx. fillRect(s.x + s.r, s.y - s.r, 2, 2);
        ctx. fillRect(s.x - s.r, s.y + s.r, 2, 2);

    });

    //ground

    ctx.fillStyle = "#2F4F4F";
    ctx.fillRect(0, floor, wid, hei-floor);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(trans, 0);

    //pillars
    ctx.fillStyle = pPat;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ccc";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < pillars.length; i++){
        var pill = pillars[i];
        ctx.fillRect(pill.x, pill.y, pill.w, pill.h);
        ctx.strokeRect(pill.x, pill.y, pill.w, pill.h);
    }

    // stripe
    ctx.fillStyle = gPat;
    ctx.fillRect(-trans, floor+2, wid, 15);
    ctx.restore();

    //rainbowwwwws
    rainbows.forEach(function(r){

        ["red","orange","blue","green","blue","indigo"].forEach(function(color, i){
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(r.x - speed, r.y-9 + i*3, speed+1, 3);
        });
    });

    //player
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(player.x, player.y);
    ctx.rotate(player.v*Math.PI/18);
    ctx.drawImage(sprite, - 17,  - 10);
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.fillStyle = "#97FFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, floor, wid, 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#2F4F4F";
    ctx.fillRect(0, floor+1, wid, 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#97FFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, floor+17, wid, 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#2F4F4F";
    ctx.fillRect(0, floor+17, wid, 1);


    //score
    ctx.font = "bold 30px monospace";
    var hScore = "best:" + (score > high ? score : high),
        sWid = ctx.measureText(hScore).width,
        sY = 50;

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(score, 12, floor + sY + 2);
    ctx.fillText(hScore, wid - sWid - 10, floor + sY + 2);  
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText(score, 10, floor + sY);
    ctx.fillText(hScore, wid - sWid - 12, floor + sY);
}

function adjust() {
    if (trans%pillSpace === 0){
        var h;
        pillars.push({
            x: -trans + wid,
            y: 0,
            w: pillWid,
            h: (h = Math.random() * (floor - 300) + 100)
        });

        pillars.push({
            x: -trans + wid,
            y: h + pillGap,
            w: pillWid,
            h: floor - h - pillGap
        });
    }

    pillars = pillars.filter(function(pill){

        return -trans < pill.x + pill.w;
    });




    player.v += gravity;
    if (player.v > termVel){
        player.v = termVel;
    }
    player.y += player.v;

    if (player.y < player.r) {
      player.y = player.r;
      player.v = 0;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < pillars.length; i++){
        var pill = pillars[i];
        if (pill.x + trans < player.x + player.r && 
            pill.x + pill.w + trans > player.x - player.r){           

            if (player.y - player.r > pill.y &&
                player.y - player.r < pill.y + pill.h){
                colider = true
                running = false;
                render();
                break;
            }
            if (player.y + player.r < pill.y + pill.h &&
                player.y + player.r > pill.y){
                colider = true
                running = false;
                render();
                break;
            }
            if (!pill.passed && i%2 == 1){
                score++;
                pill.passed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (player.y + player.r - player.v > floor) {
        player.y = floor - player.r;
        running = false;
        colider = true;
        render();
    }
}

document.onmousedown = function () {
    if (running) {
        player.v = thrust;
    } else if (!colider) {
        running = true;
    } else {
        if (score > high){
            localStorage.setItem("high", score);
        }
        init();
    }
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="stage" width="400" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: What browser? Make sure you are supporting this browser you are viewing with the technology you are using.

Comment: `loop()` was called but you never created the function. It's always a good idea to look at the console to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling `document.getElementById('stage')` before `#stage` exists in the DOM.

Javascript is run in the order that it is loaded into the page.  So, you could either move the Javascript to the bottom of your HTML document, or us an `onload` event listener.

In detail, as the page loads, things at the top of the page are pulled in and parsed first.  When a `<script>` tag is encountered, the browser automatically runs the Javascript immediately -- before it has reached the body of the page.  Your CodePen was likely set to run the code after the page had loaded completely, but when you moved it all to it's own page you were now running it before load.